# How to fetch count from the sub-table with multiple groups by using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 |
| 2 | User2 |

and check-in table

| id | userid | venue_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2022-04-06 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-04-06 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-04-06 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2022-04-07 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2022-04-07 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2022-04-06 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2022-04-07 |

I need user table records along with the count of all checked in
all-time checked in
Today checked in
yesterday checked in
with the group by date and venue_id using MySQL Query

**Expected result**
Today's date: 2022-04-07
Yesterday's date: 2022-04-06

| id | name | All-time Checked | Today checked | Yesterday checked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | User2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional sum to calculate the Today's and Yesterday's counts:

```
select 
  u.id, 
  u.name,
  count(distinct concat(c.venue_id, c.created_at)) as 'All-time Checked',
  count(
    if(c.created_at=current_date(), concat(c.venue_id, c.created_at), null)
  ) as 'Today checked',
  count(distinct 
    if(c.created_at=date_add(current_date(), interval -1 day), concat(c.venue_id, c.created_at), NULL)
  ) as 'Yesterday checked'
from user u
  join checkin c on c.userid=u.id
group by u.id, u.name
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w6b7tYNTJfr7bXLdW1d3gG/1)

Comment: Unknown column 'c.created_at' in 'field list'

Comment: @Safan Check the table and column names. DB-Fiddle added

Comment: As per your query the result is wrong, you can see my expected result, same venue id on the same date will calculate count 1, need to add group by created_at and venue_id

Comment: What is the id column in your result set? How does the `venue_id` relate to the end result? What is the logic for User1 to get 4 All-time Checked?

Comment: id and name both are from the user table and the same venue_id is on the same date 2022-04-06. so, it will count as only 1, the same venue will count as one for each date

Comment: On date 07 , user 1 have 2 record on that date and both venues are different so count: 2,

Comment: ON date 06, there 3 records for user 1 but the same venue multiple times on the same date, so count:2,

Comment: @Safan See the upated query based on question clarification

Comment: Hi @slaakso, can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792953/how-to-fetch-count-from-the-sub-table-with-multiple-date

Comment: I need both in single query, this page result for checked in and invited count as per above link

Comment: Hi @slaakso, can you provide the query for this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71792953/how-to-fetch-count-from-the-sub-table-with-multiple-date . Actully one person already answered but that query taking 40 sec for the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
SQL

> UNION
> Operator

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).