# How to fetch count from the sub-table with multiple date

Tags: mysql

I have a user table

| id | name | number | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 102 | 2022-02-03 |
| 2 | User2 | 103 | 2022-02-06 |
| 3 | User3 | 123456 | 2022-02-07 |
| 4 | User4 | 1234567 | 2022-02-07 |
| 5 | User5 | 1234568 | 2022-04-08 |

and invite table

| id | invited_by | invited_to_number | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123456 | 2022-04-05 12:03:03 |
| 2 | 2 | 123456 | 2022-04-05 17:13:23 |
| 2 | 1 | 1234567 | 2022-04-07 17:13:23 |
| 2 | 1 | 1234568 | 2022-04-07 17:13:23 |
| 2 | 2 | 1234565 | 2022-04-08 17:13:23 |

I need user table records along with the count of all invited registered in
all-time accepted in
Today accepted in
yesterday accepted in
with the group by number using MySQL Query
Count will only go to those users who were invited first
and after successfully registered count will add to the invited the user

So, the **Expected result** is
Today Date: 2022-04-08

| id | name | all_time_accepted | Today's accepted | yesterday accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | User2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | User3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | User4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | User5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count only today's or yesterday's invites, place a boolean condition (like `DATE(i.created_at) = @today_date`) inside the select expression. The condition will evaluate to 1 (if true) or 0 (if false), which means that if you `SUM()`, you will get the number of rows satisfying this condition.

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.name,
  SUM(
    u1.id IS NOT NULL
    AND i1.id IS NULL
  ) AS all_time_accepted,
  IFNULL(SUM(
    u1.id IS NOT NULL
    AND i1.id IS NULL
    AND DATE(i.created_at) = @today_date
  ), 0) AS today_accepted,
  IFNULL(SUM(
    u1.id IS NOT NULL
    AND i1.id IS NULL
    AND DATE(i.created_at) = @today_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ), 0) AS yesterday_accepted
FROM 
  (SELECT @today_date := CURDATE()) AS var,
  `user` u
LEFT JOIN `invite` i
  ON i.invited_by = u.id
LEFT JOIN `user` u1
  ON u1.number = i.invited_to_number
LEFT JOIN `invite` i1
  ON i1.invited_to_number = i.invited_to_number
  AND i1.created_at < i.created_at
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: the count will only add if the user register with that number, and today's date means today registered, same as yesterday, you can check in the user table

Comment: Also, there is some other logic, you can see in the invite table there are 2 people invited to the same number, and that number is registered in the user table so the count will only add in user1. because he invited first

Comment: @Safan Please see my updated query.

Comment: Please see here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9wuT19cWK6b4pVBkqfkyBw/3

Comment: @Safan Add `SET SESSION sql_mode='';` before the query.

Comment: Please check my expected result, as per your query result is different, user 1 has 3 counts all time. and count should be based on the user registered date

Comment: @Safan See my forked fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oATn6uD6DthkWeJgd1qawh/0 I have fixed `>` to `<` in the query and fixed some of your values which didn't match values in your original question. Now it works good, but User1 has 0 today's accepted and 2 yesterday's accepted, which is however correct I believe.

Comment: HI, this query is taking too much to to find result from my live database

Comment: @Safan Is the query also slow when you delete selected columns (keep only `u.id`) and just do the join? If so, try to add indexes on columns of joined tables to speed up the join.